# Not able to Login in to my wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I been working on a theme for wordpress. But after assigning it, i have done a mistake.
I have gone through Settings - General and then changed the site url to some thing like:

`http://websiteurl.com/` to http://websiteurl.com/index/`

Now I can't login to my admin/dashboard panel.
earlier when i try to login to my dashboard, it shows a url of 
`websiteurl.com/wp-login/` now it shows something like `websiteurl.com/index/wp-login/`

Even I tried removing `index` in the url and tried to login, but still it redirects to the same `websiteurl.com/index/wp-login/`

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `index` from database directly, `wp_options` table.

Update `siteurl` item from there, something like this

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'your_new_url' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_id` = 1;
```

Comment: Ok, but the main database is from other guy, he just gave me access like, he gave me user name, password and admin login url , and i opened it in chrome.. Is there anyting else i can do?

Comment: No you need to have db access, to try above change.

Comment: So, since it the other guy who has the database. and since he has no idea about these coding and so. can tell me what should i ask to get access to his databse.. ?

Comment: If you have FTP access and I assume you have you can upload some php  mysql admin script to get DB access, for instance: http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/